# Get access token of user after they install a package from AppExchange

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, appexchange, connected-apps

Is there any way to get access token of user (to external system) who install my package from AppExchange. I have seen an OAuth flow when I try to install any package from AppExchange, does that mean a user will prompt to OAuth when it clicks on Install button & does that follow the definition(call back URL) of connected app inside the managed package.

However, I have bundled a connected app within a managed package. But doesn't seems to get OAuth screen when installing on other dev org by use of installation link for testing.

Basically I need access token of every user to my external system after someone installs my app from AppExchange.

Comment: @identigral I guess no. I have a connected app in my managed package with client key & secret. Point here is, after installing a package from AppExchange, does the OAuth flow start automatically based on my connected app ? Basically I need access token of every user to my external system after someone installs my app from AppExchange

Comment: Packaging a connected app in your package is not the way to go. The right way to do oauth with a managed package is described in that answer.

Comment: Got it @identigral that means I need to separately invoke the authentication method on my platform (not Salesforce) by using my client key & secret to obtain user's access_token?

Comment: Yes. In [oAuth terms](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749): your platform will act as the client, the connected app is the authorization server and the SF org where your app will be installed is the resource server. Your platform will ask the user to grant access to their stuff in SF on their behalf.

Comment: Got it! @identigral is there any way to auto redirect a user to perform OAuth after they install app from appExchange, maybe some apex class on **post installation script ?** or is there any way to pass general information to my external service after app installation, such as user's name or email address ?

Comment: You can call your platform from the post-install script and your platform can then initiate the oAuth sequence.